# solve 3 unknows ;

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

I would like to have some help on this problem:

> Given the following system:
>   $$
> \begin{aligned}
> a + b + c &= 6\\
> a^2 + b^2 + c^2 &= 14\\
> a^3 + b^3 + c^3 &= 36
> \end{aligned}
> $$

Without guessing or using computer can we solve this system ?

Thanks for your help

Comment: this problem can be solved by using polynomial

Comment: By algebraic manipulation.. squaring and cubing $ (ab+bc+ca)=11, \, (a+b)(b+c)(c+a) = 60 $

Comment: Can you explain how please ?

Answer (score 5):

Note that the left-hand side of each of the three equations is a [symmetric polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_polynomial) in $a, b$ and $c$. These can be written in terms of the elementary symmetric polynomials in $a, b$ and $c$, which are
\begin{align*}
u &= a+ b + c \\
v &= ab + bc + ca \\
w &= abc.
\end{align*}
This way, we obtain the following system
\begin{align*}
u &= 6 \\
u^2 - 2v &= 14 \\
u^3 + 3w - 3uv &= 36
\end{align*}
which has a unique solution, namely $u = 6, v = 11$ and $w = 6$. So, we have to solve  the system
\begin{align*}
a+ b + c &= 6\\
ab + bc + ca &= 11\\
abc &= 6.
\end{align*}
By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta's_formulas), $a, b$ and $c$ are the roots of the polynomial equation
$$
x^3 - 6x^2 + 11x - 6 = 0.
$$
Since $x = 1, x = 2$ and $x = 3$ are the three roots of this equation, we can conclude that the only solution to the given system is $(1, 2, 3)$, up to permutation.

Comment: a,b,c, is symetric